# Javascript dosen't get regonized by HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a javascript function that should make the letters in a paragraf come from the bottom than fade but when I insert it in the html it just shows plain text ... The function should work , I think I am doing something wrong calling it to html . The text that I am trying to animate is the one in the the header "Text is text".

Main HTML code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/javascripit.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/utilities.css">


</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    
    <div class ="main">
        <div class="navbar ">
        
          <div class="container flex lead ">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="features.html">Proiecte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs.html">Recenzii</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <h1 class="ml7">
                    <span class="text-wrapper">
                      <span class="letters">Text is text</span>
                    </span>
                  </h1>
                  
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
                  
            </div>
            <div class="social sm">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code + utilites

```
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  
  min-height: 80px; 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
}
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}


.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.navbar .social a{

  margin: 0 2px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.navbar .social > *:nth-child(3){
  font-size: 28px;
  
}
.ml7 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.7em;
}
.ml7 .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-right: 0.05em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ml7 .letters {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  align-self: start;
  
}
.main {
  min-height: 100vh; /*add*/
  height: 3000px; /*this is a test rule*/
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

And the javascript function

```
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml7 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml7 .letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    translateX: ["0.55em", 0],
    translateZ: 0,
    rotateZ: [180, 0],
    duration: 750,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: (_el, i) => 50 * i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml7',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

Comment: Your HTML attempts to load your Javascript as if it were a style sheet. Look at your browser dev tools and you'll probably see an error in the Javascript console. Use `<script src="whatever.js"></script>` to load scripts.

Comment: I think O. Jones has probably spotted the issue because I tried your code in jsbin and it seems to work fine. https://jsbin.com/vayabaroto/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/javascripit.js">` is not how you load a JS file. Use `<script>` tag

Comment: And 1 question , when I load it with <script></script> , where do I place it ? I've seen some tutorials that put it at the end , some at the beggining in the head

Comment: @VlAdTbK if you put the script tag at the end, it runs after the html above it has loaded (which is often convenient).

Comment: And at the end it mens after </html> or before it ?

Comment: Just before `</body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML attempts to load your Javascript as if it were a style sheet. Look at your browser dev tools and you'll probably see an error in the Javascript console. Use `<script src="whatever.js"></script>` to load scripts.  In your case this is probably:

```
<script src="javascript/javascripit.js"></script> /*mis-spelled name?? */
```

And, you asked in a comment about where to put your <`script></script>` tags. Many people put them at the end of the HTML page, immediately before the `</body>` tag. This lets the browser fetch image objects needed to render the page before it fetches Javascript code, and gives a better user experience.

Regardless of where you put your `<script></script>` tags, Javascript code like yours to manipulate the Document Object Model (DOM) of the page should be run as an event handler for [the `DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event). In other words, wrap your Javascript in this.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    /* all your Javascript goes here */
});
```

That way it won't run before the page is loaded. If you don't do this and your Javascript does happen to run before your HTML is completely loaded, your `.querySelector()` operations may return null, causing your Javascript to fail.

Browsers try to do a lot of things in parallel to speed up their click-to-page-visible times.

Comment: Now that I looked more into it I found a weird problem that i need to use my java scripts ( both from my files and from site) twice in the html code like this https://imgur.com/DKKkfey and https://imgur.com/yrgDu3y ... So basicaly both at the beginning of the code and at the end , if I cut one of those the code won't work , why is that ?